# Check if an array of words exist in a string

Tags: php, performance, find, substring

We have a function in PHP, [`in_array`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.in-array.php), which checks if the given value is present in an array. I guess I wanna do a reverse of it. I have a set of strings:

```
$words = array("hello", "world");
```

And, I wanna check, if a given string has these words, by giving parameters whether `all` or `any`.

```
$string = "Hello, World!";
$second = "Hello and Welcome!";
in_string($words, $string, "all");
in_string($words, $string, "any");
```

What I have right now is, using [`stripos()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.stripos.php). I do not wanna use `regex`.

#### Current Code:

```
<?php
    /**
    * Checks if the given words is found in a string or not.
    * 
    * @param Array $words The array of words to be given.
    * @param String $string The string to be checked on.
    * @param String $option all - should have all the words in the array. any - should have any of the words in the array
    * @return boolean True, if found, False if not found, depending on the $option
    */
    function in_string ($words, $string, $option)
    {
        if ($option == "all")
            foreach ($words as $value)
                $isFound = $isFound && (stripos($string, $value) || false);
        else
            foreach ($words as $value)
                $isFound = $isFound || (stripos($string, $value) || false);
        return $isFound;
    }
?>
```

#### My question is, can this be improved? Any thoughts?

---

#### Update #1: Current Code Updated:

```
/**
* Checks if the given words is found in a string or not.
* 
* @param Array $words The array of words to be given.
* @param String $string The string to be checked on.
* @param String $option all - should have all the words in the array. any - should have any of the words in the array
* @return boolean True, if found, False if not found, depending on the $option
*/
function in_string ($words, $string, $option)
{
    if ($option == "all")
    {
        $isFound = true;
        foreach ($words as $value)
            $isFound = $isFound && (stripos($string, $value) !== false);
        return $isFound;
    }
    else
    {
        $isFound = true;
        foreach ($words as $value)
            if (stripos($string, $value) !== false) return true;
        return $isFound;
    }
}
```

Now the function is working as expected. But I need a better performance in the `foreach()` part and all. Anything possible for improvements?

---

#### Update #2: Improvements Added

```
<?php
    /**
    * Checks if the given words is found in a string or not.
    * 
    * @param Array $words The array of words to be given.
    * @param String $string The string to be checked on.
    * @param String $option all - should have all the words in the array. any - should have any of the words in the array
    * @return boolean True, if found, False if not found, depending on the $option
    */
    function in_string ($words, $string, $option)
    {
        if ($option == "all")
        {
            foreach ($words as $value)
                if (stripos($string, $value) === false)
                    return false;
            return true;
        }
        else
        {
            foreach ($words as $value)
                if (stripos($string, $value) !== false)
                    return true;
            return false;
        }
    }
?>
```

Comment: In your comparison you will skip finding words at the 0 position of string. Use "stripos(..) === false" in comparison.

Comment: If you want to return boolean you should declare $isFound at the begining of your function. In your case when it's noting found you'll get NULL.

Comment: Look, in PHP there're two functions "strpos" and "stripos" and there isn't one big function with a parapeter "i", so I think you have to make two functions instead of one. This approach have better performance and usability.

Comment: @infous What difference will it make if I use two functions instead of one, when I am going to give one option at any given point of time?

Comment: The difference is that you'll have minus one comparison (if highload, it may matter) and IMHO better usability.

Comment: Hey, @infous! Good point you have got! Thanks. :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
<?php
/**
* Checks if the given words is found in a string or not.
* 
* @param Array $words The array of words to be given.
* @param String $string The string to be checked on.
* @param String $option all - should have all the words in the array. any - should have any of the words in the array
* @return boolean True, if found, False if not found, depending on the $option
*/
function in_string ($words, $string, $option)
{
    if ($option == "all") {
        $isFound = true;
        foreach ($words as $value) {
            $isFound = $isFound && (stripos($string, $value) !== false); // returns boolean false if nothing is found, not 0
            if (!$isFound) break; // if a word wasn't found, there is no need to continue
        }
    } else {
        $isFound = false;
        foreach ($words as $value) {
            $isFound = $isFound || (stripos($string, $value) !== false);
            if ($isFound) break; // if a word was found, there is no need to continue
        }
    }
    return $isFound;
}
?>
```

Just the same code as the person below me, with the break; added. I don't have enough rep to comment apparently

Comment: Shouldn't that be `if (isFound)`?

Comment: I have simplified your code. Now can we progress from this? Check out the **Update #2**.

Answer (score 1):

Divide the logic and you'll get simpler code in each function, better performance and each function will solve a concrete task.

```
<?php
function in_string_all ($string, $words) {
    $isFound = true;
    foreach ($words as $value) {
        $isFound = $isFound && stripos($string, $value) !== false;
        if (!$isFound) 
            break;
    }
    return $isFound;
}

function in_string_any ($string, $words) {
    foreach ($words as $value) 
        if (stripos($string, $value) !== false)
            return true;
    return false;
}
?>
```

Comment: It is no bad to have it in the same function. I am just thinking of the loop thingy. Yeah, now your code and my updated code are looking almost same!

Comment: OK. I like update #2 but it's better to create two different functions, it's minus one comparison.

Answer (score 1):

Using strpos does not work because it will return true for partial string matches. examples searching "in" in "insersection" results in a false positive.
Here is an alternative extracting words from the target string and making an intersection between arrays.

```
/**
 * Checks if a array of given words is found in a string.
 * 
 * @param array $words The array of words to be given.
 * @param string $string The string to be checked on.
 * @param boolean $exactMatch true - should have all the words in the array. false - should have any of the words in the array
 * @param boolean $insensitive true to compare insensitive. false to compare sensitive
 * @return boolean True, if found, False if not found, depending on the $option
 */
private function arrayInString (array $words, $string, $exactMatch = true, $insensitive = true)
{
    $stringArr = explode(" ", preg_replace('/[^a-z0-9]+/i', ' ', $string));
    if ($insensitive) {
        $words = array_map('strtolower', $words);
        $stringArr = array_map('strtolower', $stringArr);
    }
    $intersectionCount = count(array_intersect($words, $stringArr));
    if ($exactMatch && $intersectionCount == count($words)) {
        return true;
    }
    if (!$exactMatch && $intersectionCount > 0) {
        return true;
    }

    return false;
}
```

Comment: Hey man. Appreciate your effort. I have no clue why and when did I ask this question. But I clearly mentioned I don't want a regex based solution. But yeah, nice one.

Answer (score 0):

Use [`strpos()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.strpos.php) instead of [`substr()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.substr.php) or [`strstr()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.strstr.php) because you only care about the word being present, you don't need to parse anything out. According to the docs, it is faster.

From the [Manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strstr.php):

> If you only want to determine if a particular needle occurs within haystack, use the faster and less memory intensive function strpos() instead.

Comment: It was `stripos`, that is in the original code. My typo. Please update your answer. `:)`

Answer (score 0):

You need to init `$isFound`, use `stripos()` for case-insensitive search, and check that `stripos()` returns `false`, not 0. (0 means that `$string` starts with `$value`)

```
function in_string ($words, $string, $option)
{
if ($option == "all") {
    $isFound = true;
    foreach ($words as $value) {
        $isFound = $isFound && (stripos($string, $value) !== false);
    }
} else {
    $isFound = false;
    foreach ($words as $value) {
        $isFound = $isFound || (stripos($string, $value) !== false);
    }
}
return $isFound;
}
```

Comment: Okay, sure. But I want something which doesn't hit the performance. :)